# I need to solve a system of partial differential equations. I need guidance.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The system of differential equations are as follows
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=k_1(1+f),\\
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=k_2(1+f).
\end{cases}
$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are two different constants and obviously $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Can any one help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Please share your work or thoughts so far. Additionally, please use mathjax notation.

Comment: If you assume (for a second) that only the first equation exists and $f$ is a function only of $x$, can you solve it?

Comment: Consider the change of variable $g=\log(1+f)$.